# Как активировать режим мониторинга на Wi-Fi адаптаре

Tags: сеть, wifi, kali-linux, мониторинг

Недавно купила сетевой адаптер TL-WN722N v3.20. Его очень нахваливали, потому что он совместим со всеми ОС. А тут такая лажа произошла, что его нельзя перевести в режим мониторинга. Может кто знает, как это можно исправить, не возвращая адаптер?

Answer (score 0):

TL-WN722N идет на разных чипах - у меня таких адаптеров 3 штуки - два переводятся в режим мониторинга. При покупке адаптера надо смотреть именно версию, а не только модель и искать по wikidevi и xda какой именно чип стоит.

На третьей версии обычно стоит Realtek RTL8188EUS. Попробуйте собрать драйвер https://github.com/quickreflex/rtl8188eus - в ридми заявленна поддержка мониторинга

Comment: Делаю всё как написано, но ошибка в последних командах: command failed: Not such device (-19)

Comment: Модель чипа в lsusb какую показывает?